# Pass encrypted credentials to run batch command in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, credentials, password-encryption

Below is the PowerShell script to fetch the Networker daily status report.

Here password is given in plain text and pass the same in batch command.

```
######## Define variables
$ver="0.1"
$date = Get-Date -Format D  

####### customer info
$cust="FOO"
$site="Chicago"
$nwsvr="CHNetworker1"

#####nmc crdentials
$user="administrator"
$pwd="foobar11"

######## where to store report files
$reportstore="\\10.10.216.9\chdd4200_bkup_infra\NW_Bkup_Reports\"

####### note: JAVA_HOME must be set in gstclreport.bat script

$gstclrpt="D:\EMC NetWorker\Management\GST\bin\gstclreport.bat"
$rptformat="csv"
$now =  get-date -uformat "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"
$rpt="/Reports/NetWorker Backup Status/Group Summary by Client and Server"
$rpttmp="rpttmp"
```

Begin Report Script

```
######## Run batch file to generate csv report
try
{
& $gstclrpt -u $user -P $pwd -r `"$rpt`" -x $rptformat -o landscape -f `"$reportstore$rpttmp`" -C `"Group Start Time`" `"1 day ago`" -C `"Server Name`" $nwsvr
}

catch [system.exception]
{
"caught a system exception"
}
```

How to pass the username and password as input prompt and should be in encrypted form. Also How to pass the credentials in batch arguments( highlighted below) so that it wont be stored in shell for security purpose.

Comment: I have tried to format your code for you. Please confirm that it is exactly how it is intended to look, so that we do not misunderstand anything. If it is not, please try formatting it properly yourself.  _There is [site help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) to assist you with that_.

Comment: You cannot pass the credentials in an encrypted form if the command to which you are providing the password doesn't accept the credentials in an encrypted form.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart If i use below commands to store the password :                                                        $credential = Get-Credential
$user= $credential.UserName                                                                                                    $pass = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password                                                                         This is working but not sure if password will store somewhere in shell.

Comment: By calling the `GetNetworkCredential()` method you are decrypting the password into memory. Normally this would not be written to disk (but it _might_ be: For example, if the machine blue-screens and your password is a part of the memory dump). The point is that if your command-line tool requires an unencrypted password you will have to give it one.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart   - I found this also. will this decrypt the password into memory?                                                                                                 
$password = Read-Host "Enter the password" -AsSecureString 
$password = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($password)
$password = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringBSTR($password)

Comment: As you said , it requires unencrypted password. will that not stored in memory?

Comment: Yes, it will be in memory in plain-text because you're explicitly decrypting it. (How long it will remain in memory in plain-text depends on when .NET will garbage-collect it, and you have no control over that.)